Ardour not recording audio on Ubuntu 22.04.4
I use Ubuntu 22.04.4, with KDE Plasma or XFCE as a desktop environment, for all of my multimedia design needs. I regularly record, using Audacity, from a Snowball Blue microphone, and it works fine. However, I am approaching a project in which I will benefit from something as multitrack, studio-oriented, and sophisticated as Ardour. I would like to have it up and running.
I'll readily admit that I'm more of a graphics guy than a sound studio guy these days and I may be missing something fundamental.
Ardour seems to think it's working fine, for both the package manager version and the self-compiled Ardour 8.x. It shows ALSA, JACK, and PulseAudio in its opening window, and I've tried all three. However, in spite of arming the track, verifying that the microphone is plugged in, and pressing record, I get a total flat-line of audio.
Closing it and switching to Audacity, I get perfectly normal behavior and excellent sound quality.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I feel like I'm missing something in its audio interface. Can someone walk me through why Ardour, even downloaded directly from the package manager, might be unable to detect input from any device?
UPDATE: I've recorded the behavior using two different microphones, and have posted the video here: https://youtu.be/OowwKHtdvBU
Hopefully someone can kindly help me get to the bottom of this after seeing the issue.

Try adding yourself to the audio group with the terminal command sudo adduser $USER audio, then logoff and login. Groups are set up at login time.

@waltinator Thanks for the idea, but that didn't seem to do it. I added myself to audio, logged out, and logged back in, and there's no change. I may put a private video together to illustrate this issue.
